# webView onTouchEvent

Tags: android, webview

i'm trying to catch the onTouchEvent of a WebView, in order to handle actions like
`MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`, `MOVE` and `CANCEL`. I made a simple example but did not success, however i succed with just a View. Am i missing something?

Thanks

```
public class HelloWebView extends Activity {

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(new MyWebView(this));
 }

 private static class MyWebView extends WebView {

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
   int action = event.getAction();
   Log.w("TouchEvent","Touch" + action);
   Log.w("HitResult",this.getHitTestResult().toString());
   switch (action) {
   case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN): // Touch screen pressed
    break;
   case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP): // Touch screen touch ended
    break;
   case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE): // Contact has moved across screen
    break;
   case (MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL): // Touch event cancelled
    break;
   }
   return super.onTouchEvent(event);
  }

  public MyWebView(Context context) {
   super(context);
   this.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   this.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
  }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because you are using a WebView, it has already handled much of the onTouchEvent movements.  I haven't got an answer right now but at least I can tell you what the problem is!